# Modal when page first open hidden but covers top nav-pills links

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into some weird problems, i am new to javascript, twitter bootstrap etc. 
I am doing a form-feed modal fade at the moment, the forms opens fine and hides ok.

But the problem is when the page first loaded in Chrome, i can see the form appears at the top quickly and then hide to the top of the page, it doesnt happen in Safari.

The Main problem is that in both Browser, when the page is loaded, after what happened above, i can not click on the nav-pills, but if i make the browser really wide i can, or after i opened and closed the modal form i can as well.

I believe its the initial positioning thats causing that but not sure how to fix it.

Login Button

```
 <a id ="Login" class="btn btn-success btn-lg1" type="button" style="width:100px;" href="#login-feed-form"  data-toggle = "modal">Login</a>
```

The Form

```
<div id="login-feed-form" class="form-feed modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <br>





        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Need code to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I editted the code, Wondering how do i change the position of the form-feed modal fade and its initial position

Comment: Realize this is late, but if you're still having the issue, then can you reproduce it on a site like [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)?